# Multiple databases for clients

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I need help with databases MySQL.

I am building a Customer Management System where more than 1000 users will use this system and each user will have their own clients which in turn they can have more than 100 clients or more (unlimited). I am thinking should I have separate databases in MySQL or all in one database for the user? So when user creates their own account it will automatically creates all the database files for that user only and another user will have another separate database and so on.

Please help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design

Comment: 100,000 records is not a lot of data. Having separate databases would be insane.

Comment: I would liek to here something not just posting links. Thanks.

Comment: @Quentin how about 1,000,000 (1M) records? I am just intereesting if more then 10,000 users using same database will it be slow down and everyuser will create products and manage their users at the same time?

Comment: well its on how you optimize your queries and PHP not how many databases you use

Comment: SO shoudl I use same database and store all the bloody 10,000 users and their cleints with all the products details? or Seperate each user to their own seperated database? it still will be the same mysql just difirent database.. =\

Comment: Im using a database with 1M+ records and no problem, you should use just the same database for each user, using more will make a mess

Comment: You should rather be thinking about this from a security point of view – what data will each user have access to, and what might happen if f.e. by some mistake in your scripts they will get access to data they are not supposed to access?

Comment: what do you mean by using more? you mean using multi databases for each user?

Comment: well i would put it all in the same database, having multiple databases would not improve efficiency. A database is just a logical way of grouping some tables, so in your case eveything is related so should just go in the database. you should really need to worry if you are doing simple selects even on a database with a few million records.

Comment: @CBroe I will secure all the wholes not big deal just worring about having all the data and all the shit in one databases for me in my head its already f mess....

Comment: well DB are designed for this exact purpose, its all about how you write your queries to extract the data that will effect speed. Also how complicated the structure/ model of your problem is.

Comment: this databdase will have -creating clients and their products, generating invoices and full cms functions and more which I cant list them here. its a big CMS and I joning more then 6 tables at the same time to pull the data.

Comment: _“I will secure all the holes”_ – yes, this is what every developer thinks and tries to do – and it still goes wrong somewhere on the web multiple times a day. Different databases at least for the 1st-level-users would avoid any “leaks” because those users could be given corresponding database accounts so that they can only access their own data.

Comment: well as long as you index your Foreign keys you should be fine, if you have a user table, each user mapping to 100+ records in the clients table thats not really a lot of data in DB terms.

Comment: @CBroe that is one way to do it, but then the web user thats accesses the database is going to need more access then you want it to have. It would need create rights for both DB and tables. This would be a security hole in its self.

Comment: also from a maintenance point of view if 12months down the line you decide to change slightly how it is structured rather than one database schema to change you now have shed loads of DB that now are in the wrong structure

Comment: SO the final answer is use 1 database for 10,000 users and each user maps to more than 100 records will be fine to be stored in the same database?

Comment: @MadDokMike agreed this will be shit lot of work.

Comment: yes because that only gives you 1,000,000 records in your user_client table

Comment: how many records am I allowed to have in MySql database? is there a limit to it?

Comment: unlimited, you are only limited by the amount of space on the hard drive

Comment: haha no shit, and its doesnt matter how complicated the database structure it will be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you describe is known as "multi-tennant" architecture.

There's no right or wrong answer - there are a whole bunch of considerations.

Data size is definitely one - but the numbers you mention aren't large enough to make much of a difference. 1 million rows in MySQL is trivial (as long as you can use indexing).

Other considerations:

- Maintainability: having one "large" database means new versions only have to be migrated once - adding a column or table, creating a new index etc. is likely to be conceptually much easier, as you don't have to repeat the same script for each client.  However, some operations may put all of your clients off-line for hours; this might be a bad thing.
- Versioning: if you intend to upgrade the solution over time, e.g adding new features etc., having a single database means you have to upgrade all your clients at the same time, whether they want to or not. It reduces the effort and complexity, but some clients may not be ready for the upgrade (e.g. if they're exporting data from the system and you're changing the schema).
- Service levels: many SaaS providers offer different service levels. You might consider "bronze" for shared infrastructure, and "gold" with dedicated infrastructure.
- Row length isn't the only thing determining system performance - if you let your users create their own reports, that could slow the system down; you might have complicated scripts that run overnight to archive data etc. It may be necessary to partition customers after all once those problems become insurmountable.

Comment: I need probably study more on mysql databases